# bat file for changing the timestamp of a file

Tags: batch-file, timestamp

I would like to have a bat file find a specific file within a directory and have it update the time stamp to be current and or synched with the time of activating the bat file.

Comment: You want to change the modify time of the file? [touch](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) can do that. You'd have to put it in some sort of script or FOR loop, but touch will do the hard part.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use "touch.exe" to accomplish this.  A simple script like this will prove the case:

```
@echo off

ECHO Test1:
SET FILENAME=test.xml
copy /b %FILENAME% +,,
dir %FILENAME%

timeout 64

ECHO Test2:
copy /b %FILENAME%,,+
dir %FILENAME%

pause
```

This proves that there are 2 different ways to do this, syntactically.

Comment: What is the signification of the 2 commas? Where to get a doc about it?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use [touch](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) (already suggested in Jubjub Bandersnatch's comment):

change the `modification time` from all TXT files to now:

```
touch -m *.txt
```

---

```
Usage: touch [OPTION]... FILE...
Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.

  -a                     change only the access time
  -c                     do not create any files
  -d, --date=STRING      parse STRING and use it instead of current time
  -f                     (ignored)
  -m                     change only the modification time
  -r, --reference=FILE   use this file's times instead of current time
  -t STAMP               use MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss] instead of current time
      --time=WORD        access -a, atime -a, mtime -m, modify -m, use -a
      --help             display this help and exit
      --version          output version information and exit

STAMP may be used without -t if none of -drt, nor --, are used.
```

Comment: thank you all for the help. Without having to install 3rd part software i added "copy copytest.txt,,+" to a bat file and place in the appropriate folder and created a shortcut to the desktop. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using:

```
copy Certain.config,,+
TIMEOUT 2
net stop Certain_Services
TIMEOUT 1
net start Certain_Services
```

it will update the Modified Date, stop and restart the services.